# GeoExplorer hyperlinks not working within attribute table

Tags: geoserver, geoexplorer

I'm testing the OpenGeo suite as a web mapping solution.

I have hyperlinks within the attribute table of some of my feature layers that should open up an image on my server. In my pop-up window it just shows as plan text(I can't click on it), as well as in the table itself within the query window of GeoExplorer.

I'm positive the link path itself is good. I feel like I'm missing something specific to GeoExplorer/GeoServer when dealing with hyperlinks in feature attribute tables.

Is special formatting required or maybe some settings in GeoServer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on you layer- click on layer properties- click on display- change the info format to "text plain".
if your links look like this: `<a href="http://mypage:8081/share/page/search?t=1577313" target="_blank">DOWNLOAD</a>` than will work.

You can custumize your pop up window if you want. Here is a useful link: http://docs.geoserver.org/2.6.x/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html